# Android finding out when activity destroyed

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, exit

currently to find out when my app exits i'm using the `onDestroy()` to execute code which closes and sockets and turns bluetooth off. Now the only problem is that `onDestroy()` is not always called, so a signal can't be sent to the remote device that the app is exiting and the bluetooth doesn't turn off. Does anybody know of a way from which I can find out if the application is exiting 100% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

Android grants to you the call of `onPause()`. `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are not granted. Put your code in `onPause()` and `onResume()`.

Comment: @dcharms OP asked for activities (from title) so I don't understand your comment

Comment: OP wants to know when the app closes, not an activity. `onPause` will be called when the user goes to another activity, not only when the app itself is closed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you define as "when my app exits". Have a read through this page for more information: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

I would suggest placing the code in the `onPause()`

Comment: But whenever onPause is called it would disable bluetooth, and it is an expensive operation to enable, send login data, resume and then disable again. When I mean exit I mean when the app is deleted from memory. Like when you swipe it away from the background apps page

Comment: But wouldn't it drain the battery to leave the bluetooth on?

Answer (score 0):

One popular method is to track your activities onPause() and onResume() callbacks and have a globalFlag like "appActivityStarted".
Then implement following algorithm:

- in onPause() set appActivityStarted = false AND start a Timer thread that will timeout after like 5 seconds
- in onResume() set the appActivityStarted = true AND cancel the Timer
- if the timeout occurs (was not cancelled) -> if (appActivityStarted == false) then you should do whatever you need to do on app stop
- don't forget the appropriate synchronization on reading/setting the flag

I have extensively tested this approach and found no issues with it.